# the button should pop up at an exact time

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>Students/introduction" style="float: left;">

<video id="lesson" width="640" height="360" controls>

<source src="/elearning/assets/videos/lesson.mp4" type="video/mp4">



</video> <br>

<input style="display: none;" type="submit" id="btn4d" value="Proceed" class="btn btn-primary btn3d pull-right">

    </form>


<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#lesson").on("timeupdate", function() {
    var videoElem = this;
    console.log(videoElem.duration);
    $('#btn4d').toggle(parseInt(videoElem.duration - videoElem.currentTime) <= 30);
  });
});
</script>
```

the above code is my view, when a user fast forwards the video, the button pops up but i need it to appear at a specific time maybe 1 min 14 seconds.if someone skips over this time the button should not show this will help discourage fast forwarding without finishing the video.thanks

Answer (score 0):

First load whole page after loading whole page after that load this script.